# React with typescript: onmouseup and onmousedown not recognizing left click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mouseevent

I have this simple piece of code which is supposed to set the mousePressed variable to true when the mouse is pressed and reset it when it is unpressed. I see that it is working well for right click and middle click but not for left click. `event.which` returns 2 and 3 respectively for middle and right clicks. What am I missing? Is there a way to get the same behaviour with onclick()? I am using react with typescript.

```
    const canvasElement = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvasElement.onmousedown = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log(event.which);
        console.log("Mouse pressed");
        console.log(this.mousePressed);
        this.mousePressed = true;
    };
    //this.onmouseDown;
    canvasElement.onmouseup =  (event: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log(event.which);
        console.log("Mouse unpressed");
        console.log(this.mousePressed);
        this.mousePressed = false;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
    canvasElement.addEventListener("pointerdown", this.onmouseDown.bind(this));
    canvasElement.addEventListener("pointermove", this.recordCoordinates.bind(this));
    canvasElement.addEventListener("pointerup", this.onmouseUp.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided before works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ktq1oda6/

Open up the console on the fiddle and you should see the correct `which`.

You probably have something else in the application that is catching the clicks. Make sure you aren't calling `e.stopPropogation` anywhere.

EDIT: I see your new solution. There was probably something else in your code causing the problem, but glad you fixed it.